# How to insert PostgreSQL timestamp with Laravel model

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 with PostgreSQL. I created PostgreSQL timestamp fields with a migration:

```
$table->dateTime('start_date');
```

I tried inserting a timestamp generated with **strtotime** and received an error:

```
Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "1383321600"
```

Hacking around it works:

```
new MyModel(array('start_date' => DB::raw("to_timestamp($start_date)")));
```

It seems like there should be a better way. Laravel itself generates timestamps without issue for the created_at and updated_at automatically-populated dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Unix timestamps created with strtotime aren't converted correctly, but true PHP DateTime objects work fine.

I switched to using [date_create](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) with the same arguments and I can insert it directly without using DB::raw.

Answer (score 1):

You must convert whatever the outcome of your `strtotime` is to the MySQL format before trying to save it.  You can do this using the `date` function.

Example

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('some time'))`

Answer (score 0):

Doc for strtotime() says

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp

In SQL databases generally, *timestamp* doesn't mean a Unix timestamp.  In SQL, if you were going to insert a timestamp into a table using standard SQL, you'd do it like this.

```
-- Implicit use
insert into table_name (column_name)
values ('2013-01-01 08:00:00');

-- Explicit use
insert into table_name (column_name)
values (timestamp '2013-01-01 08:00:00');
```